# Как имитировать, что Android VM это реальное устройство ?

Tags: android, virtualbox

Требуется установить приложение с Play Market в виртуальную машину Android X86.
Разрешение экрана VM 480х800 как у многих устройств, особых требований вроде нет:

- **Покупки через приложение**
- **Идентификационные данные**

  - Поиск аккаунтов на устройстве
- **Фото/мультимедиа/файлы**

  - Изменение/удаление данных на USB-накопителе
  - Проверка доступа к защищенному хранилищу
- **Данные о Wi-Fi-подключении**

  - Просмотр подключений Wi-Fi
- **Другое**

  - Получение данных из Интернета
  - Неограниченный доступ к Интернету
  - Просмотр сетевых подключений
  - Предотвращение переключения устройства в спящий режим
  - Подключение/отключение сети Wi-Fi

Вроде ничего особенного. Предполагаю, что какое-нибудь имя устройства или DeviceID ему не нравится, поэтому пишет, что "Приложение не совместимо с Вашим устройством".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам недавно задавался этим вопросом. Я использую [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) вместо стандартного эмулятора. Вот статья [тык](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/), как установить Play Market на виртуальное устройство. После установки у меня как и на реальном девайсе, обновилась масса приложений и заработал Play Market - подключил свой гугл аккаунт, скачал приложение и достал требуемую базу данных из него :)

Comment: Спасибо. Весьма неплохая VM. Лишена глюков x86 связанных с масштабированием VM и захватом мыши.    
Выдала теперь четкую ошибку  

    INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

и я успокоился :)

Comment: По этой проблеме все ссылаются на это [решение][1]
[1]: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте apk файл этой программы, передайте его на эмулятор и установите руками, apk можно поискать на 4pda, там же есть мануал, как устанавливать софт из маркета на несовместимые устройства.

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Это верный ответ. 
К сожалению мне это не помогает. Видимо x86 не нравится.

Comment: Скорее всего, там есть нативный код, который скомпилирован только для arm платформы. Без эмуляции arm заставить работать будет практически нереально. Но не нужно бояться и пишите реальное название приложения.

Comment: @KoVadim, clash of clans -_-